# Error NoSuchAlgorithmException while running-hmac

Tags: java, netbeans-8, hmac

I was trying hmac in Java and as a newbie, I am not able to solve the error

Error after running in NetBeans :

> Key:MTzkWlyhZxfLMv84wgr+i+pFNI0=
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
>
> -unreported exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught
>
> or declared to be thrown
>
> at hmac.HMAC.main(HMAC.java:27)
>
> Java Result: 1

My code

```
package HMAC;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import sun.misc.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Best
 */
public class HMAC {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[20];
        random.nextBytes(keyBytes);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HMACSHA1");
        System.out.println("Key:"+new BASE64Encoder().encode(key.getEncoded()));
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(key);
        mac.update("hello".getBytes("UTF8"));
        byte[] result = mac.doFinal();
        System.out.println("MAC: "+new BASE64Encoder().encode(result));

    }
    
}
```

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. Most of the IDEs point it out directly. Just add `try` and  `catch` the exception `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. This would work fine.